# The best way to databind a ListBox Selected Item to DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox

Hi New WPF programmer here. I can't seem to get this to work and I was hoping maybe you had some ideas. I'd like for when I select an Item in the User Defined table (ListBox), that it populates the data (ObservableCollection) into my datagrid. Then I'll use the Insert Edit Save buttons below for editing. Each Item in the User Defined Table (ListBox) has multiple Choice and Descriptions.

I have a XAML that looks like this:

[image]

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="805">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="210*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="233*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="315*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="47*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="217*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="86*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="89*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="81*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox  x:Name="_listbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="103" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBoxItem Content="ARNotes" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item2"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item3"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item4"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item5"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Item6"/>
    </ListBox>

    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" Grid.Column="2">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="FromCompanyTable"/>
    </ComboBox>

    <DataGrid x:Name="_grid" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=_listbox}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="24,2,0,3" Grid.Row="1" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Choice"  Width="*" Header="Choice" Binding="{Binding choice}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Descip"  Width="*" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding description}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And My Model:

```
public class NoteList : ObservableCollection<ARNotes>
{       
    public NoteList() : base()
    {
        Add(new ARNotes("A", "Adjustment"));
        Add(new ARNotes("C", "Changed"));
        Add(new ARNotes("D", "Notes"));
        Add(new ARNotes("G", "Information"));
    }
}

public class ARNotes
{
    private string choice;
    private string description;

    public ARNotes(string choice, string description)
    {
        this.choice = choice;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public string Choice
    {
        get { return choice; }
        set { choice = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `_listbox` has no object item because your literally set `content` for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemsSource needs to be a collection of items. You are setting it to a single item. You are not gaining anything by having the ListBox. I would suggest just having the DataGrid only and bind that ItemsSource to your NoteList